# WCF service resource cannot be found

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, web-config, wcf-endpoint

I have a REST WCF Service that works fine on localhost but returns the below error when deploying online:

> The resource cannot be found.

Note: My WCF service is located under the following path:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/Service.svc
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is a path error and I tried too many solutions but none worked.

Below is my `Web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" listenUri="/">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>  
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="Buffered">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="250000000" maxStringContentLength="250000000" maxArrayLength="250000000" maxBytesPerRead="250000000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">          
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

## Solutions I tried:

---

**Solution 1:**

Adding a base address to `system.serviceModel > Services > Service`

```
<host>
    <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://example.com/" />
    </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Adding a base address prefix to `system.serviceModel > serviceHostingEnvironment`

```
<baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="https://example.com/" />
</baseAddressPrefixFilters>
```

---

**Solution 3:**

Playing around with the endpoint `address` and `listenUri`

```
<endpoint address="https://example.com/api/v1/Service.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" listenUri="/">
```

---

How can I define the correct path in my `Web.config`?

*Note: In another project, I had my `.svc` file on the root directory and I used the same `Web.config` I posted above and everything worked fine. So it is definitely a path problem.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by changing `<security mode="Transport" />` and it worked!